# How to encrypt a SPSS-file using cypher

Tags: r, r-haven

Is there a way to encrypt SPSS-files (.sav) using the `cyphr`-package? Encrypting .csv works fine, but when I try to encrypt .sav, I get following error-message:

```
  Error in db_lookup(dat$ns, dat$name, file_arg) : 
  Rewrite rule for haven::write_sav not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution where I first convert the original files (*.csv and .sav) into *.rds files. After that they are encrypted. This works as intended.

With this procedure, encrypted *.rds files with the same name are created and saved in a separate folder for all *.csv and *.sav in the original folder.

Load packages:

```
library(rio)
library(stringr)
library(cyphr)
```

Set paths to the folder with original unencrypted data (`data_originals`) and to the folder to store the encrypted data (`data_encypted`):

```
path_originals <- "./data_originals"
path_encrypted <- "./data_encypted"
```

Set working directory:

```
setwd(path_originals)
```

Specify the directory in which the encrypted files are to be stored (`data_encypted`).

```
data_dir <- file.path(path_encrypted)
```

Set path of personal key:

```
path_key_user <- "~/.ssh/"
```

Create a key for the data and encrypt that key with personal key:

```
data_admin_init(data_dir, path_user = path_key_user)
```

Get the data key and add encrypted data to the directory:

```
key <- cyphr::data_key(data_dir, path_user = path_key_user)
```

For *.csv-files:

Write all *.csv files in the folder `data_originals` to a list:

```
filenames_csv <- list.files(path = path_originals, pattern = "*.csv")
```

Read in *.csv files located in the folder `data_originals`:

```
df_csv <- lapply(filenames_csv, read.csv2)
```

Create a list of what the *.csv files should be named as *.rds files:

```
filenames_csv %>% str_replace(".csv", ".rds") -> filenames_csv2rds
```

Save the *.csv files as *.rds files to the folder created for the encrypted files (`data_encrypted`):

```
for (i in 1:length(df_csv)) {
  setwd(path_encrypted)
  export(df_csv[i], filenames_csv2rds[i]) #
}
```

For *.sav-files:

Set working directory:

```
setwd(path_originals)
```

Write all *.sav files in the folder `data_originals` to a list:

```
filenames_sav <- list.files(path = path_originals, pattern = "*.sav")
```

Read in *.sav files located in the folder `data_originals`:

```
df_sav <-
  lapply(filenames_sav,
         Hmisc::spss.get,
         use.value.labels = T,
         lowername = T)
```

Create a list of what the *.sav files should be named as *.rds files:

```
filenames_sav %>% str_replace(".sav", ".rds") -> filenames_sav2rds
```

Save the *.sav files as *.rds files to the folder created for the encrypted files (`data_encrypted`):

```
for (i in 1:length(df_sav)) {
  setwd(path_encrypted)
  export(df_sav[i], filenames_sav2rds[i]) #
}
```

Write the names of the *.rds files that are now in the `data_encrypted` folder and are still to be encrypted in a list:

```
filenames <- list.files(path = path_encrypted, pattern = "*.rds")
```

Read in all *.rds files located in the folder `data_encrypted`.

```
ldf <- lapply(filenames, readRDS)
```

Define paths:

```
paths <- file.path(data_dir, paste0(filenames))
```

Encrypt and save all files in folder `data_encrypted`:

```
for (i in 1:length(ldf)) {
  for (i in 1:length(paths)) {
    encrypt(saveRDS(ldf[i], paths[i]), key)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the read/write functions aren't explicitly supported by `cyphr`, you have to specify the arguments in the relevant functions that direct to the path so encryption can happen. Do this with the `file_arg` argument.

```r
library(cyphr)
library(haven)

df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 6:4)

# save to temporary SPSS file
f <- tempfile(fileext = ".sav")

# encrypt file
key <- key_sodium(sodium::keygen())

encrypt(
  expr = write_sav(df, f),
  key = key,
  file_arg = "path"
)

# check file is encrypted
read_sav(f)
#> Error: Failed to parse /private/var/folders/b7/_6hwb39d43l71kpy59b_clhr0000gn/T/RtmpV23nxX/file1325251862c5d.sav: Invalid file, or file has unsupported features.

# decrypt the file
decrypt(
  read_sav(f),
  key,
  file_arg = "file"
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>       a     b
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     6
#> 2     2     5
#> 3     3     4
```

This is detailed in the [package README](https://github.com/ropensci/cyphr), which also covers how to register the function if you want to do this frequently.